# Filtering numbers using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am running the following MySQL query to filter the number of listings with prices within a certain range.

```
SELECT `listing_id`, `price` FROM (`listings`) 
WHERE `post_timestamp` BETWEEN (NOW() - 0 AND NOW() - 5) 
AND `price` > '0' AND `price` < '10000'
ORDER BY `post_timestamp` desc
```

**Problem:** This does not give me any results although there are rows where the price column has values between 0 and 10,000.

Now the following SQL query returns the correct results

```
SELECT `listing_id`, `price` FROM (`listings`) 
WHERE `post_timestamp` BETWEEN (NOW() - 0 AND NOW() - 5) 
AND `price` < '10000'
ORDER BY `post_timestamp` desc
```

But this query below returns no results!!

```
SELECT `listing_id`, `price` FROM (`listings`) 
WHERE `post_timestamp` BETWEEN (NOW() - 0 AND NOW() - 5) 
AND `price` > '0'
ORDER BY `post_timestamp` desc
```

This is really confusing me, wonder if anyone have an explanation/solution for this?

**Edit** The following code gives me results!

```
SELECT `listing_id`, `price` FROM (`listings`) 
WHERE `price` > '0'
```

**Field type:** int(8)

**Removing quotes** 
around numerical values do not make a difference

Comment: What is the field type of `price`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I found myself don't understand what is this explanation),
so, in short

Remove the parenthesis to :-

```
WHERE `post_timestamp` BETWEEN NOW() - 0 AND NOW() - 5 //first where clause
AND `price` < '10000'
```

It might return zero matches,
as the comparison is too short (now() - 5 seconds)

To check for last 5 days

```
WHERE `post_timestamp` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW()
AND `price` < 10000
```

Comment: Yes, the manual says "BETWEEN min AND max" simply expands to "(min <= expr AND expr <= max)"

Comment: If the -5 is in seconds, why did the 2nd query return the correct result? (rows are returned)

Comment: I did notice that the rows with `post_timestamp` earlier than 5 days were returned too... how should I change the units of -5 to -5 days?

Comment: `WHERE post_timestamp BETWEEN (1)` did not return any warning, but the rows returned were wrong, the prices include both >1000 and <1000

Comment: I think my explanation is hard to understand, I have revised the answer to get straight to the point

Comment: I think your previous explaination is good... thanks ajreal you solved many of my questions!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to quote the numeric values.

Comment: I removed the quotes on the numbers and its still the same results

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem: mySQL will automatically convert quoted values to the required target column value - in this case, `int`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Then my second guess ;-), is that the parenthesis after BETWEEN (XXX) confuse the parser into thinking XXX is one thing, and the following price clause is still part of the "between."  UPDATE: try BETWEEN NOW() - 0 AND NOW() - 5 or BETWEEN (NOW() - 0) AND (NOW() - 5)

Comment: I removed the parenthesis and its still the same

Comment: @johnpersonna - You absolutely spotted a parenthesis mismatch. You should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that you're treating `price` as a string? I mean, there are quotes surrounding the '0' and '1000' values. Try removing them.

**EDIT**

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
SELECT listing_id, price
FROM listings
WHERE post_timestamp BETWEEN (NOW() - 0) AND (NOW() - 5)
AND price < 10000
ORDER BY post_timestamp desc
```

Comment: In field type is int(8) and I removed the quotes, but still get the same results

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem: mySQL will automatically convert quoted values to the required target column value - in this case, `int`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database schema, I can't be sure, but have you tried removing the quotes from around the numerical values?

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem: mySQL will automatically convert quoted values to the required target column value - in this case, `int`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible that the field price have the value null?

Comment: I did `SELECT listing_id, price FROM (listings) 
WHERE price = NULL` and no results were returned